# via Win32 API how would you get the value of a class of SysListView32

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a c# app that reads (with thanks to this forum) the values of a native windows app via the win32 API, I can get all the text from boxes of class Edit but there is some data presented in a SysListView32 control for which I can get the handle.

So given the handle how do I get the data within the list view?

thanks

Comment: @Hans You are totally right. LVM_GETITEM passes a pointer which is not valid outside the current process, so it's not the quick solution I hoped it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VirtualAllocEx
WriteProcessMemory to initlize LVITEM
SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETITEM, WPARAM, LPARAM)
ReadProcessMemory
VirtualFreeEx
```

1. Need to allocate/free additional buffers if text is included
2. Does not work on Windows Mobile
3. Does not work across platforms, you need to compile x86 and x64 targets for 32 and 64 bit processes) and marshal the APIs with the correct bitness.
4. Does not work if blocked by UIPI.
5. Have race condition with the target process

Comment: Thank you for this, this sounds a bit beyond my skill level :( So I think I will try a different way of doing things. It require the users to do an extra couple of steps but it will be more reliable..    Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A far easier way would be to [inject a DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection), which would then obviously be inside the aforementioned process.